# Can you exceed 18 in your core stats as a level 1 character?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, ability-scores

We are making characters in Pathfinder and a player asked if they could go past 18 with racial bonuses. Now we aren't talking with any equipment, just a simple 15 point buy with pluses also from the race. I'm mostly asking because I'm pretty sure somewhere I heard that you can only go to 22, but that's with levels if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Once levels and items are involved, 22 isn’t even particularly special. Using only “common” resources (available to any class and many races), 36 is a decent number to keep in mind as “maximum” (18 base + 2 race + 5 from levels + 6 enhancement + 5 inherent), though many characters will not bother getting that high even at 20th level.

Comment: Ok That makes sense. I was wondeirng if you could go past 20 I didn't think it was an option.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can go up to 18 by buying, and then add your racial bonus.

from [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores)

> No score can be reduced below 7 or raised above 18 using [the purchase method]. See Table: Ability Score Costs for the costs of each score. After all the points are spent, apply any racial modifiers the character might have.